# Why is Select().Contains() ok while Any() is not?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I first tried the following code:

```
var statesIndirectDelete = await States
    .Where(s => deletedCountries.Any(c => c.Id == s.CountryId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

and that gave me the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The LINQ expression 'c => c.Id == EntityShaperExpression: 
    LouisHowe.core.Models.State
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.CountryId' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

so I then changed it to:

```
var statesIndirectDelete = await States
    .Where(s => deletedCountries.Select(c => c.Id)
    .Contains(s.CountryId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

and that works. But why does the first fail?

And is this (Select.Contains) the best way to:

1. I have a list of Country objects
2. From that I want to get a list of all State objects where they are all the states that have any of the countries as their parent.

In other words, if my country list is { "USA", "CANADA" } I want to get "California", "Quebec", ... but I do not want to get any states/provinces from any other country.

Comment: The Select().Contains() one simply translates to `WHERE CountryID IN (CountryIDs)`. The Any() one you are passing a list of country objects which cannot be easily translated to SQL.

Comment: @StevenManuel If you write that up as an answer I'm happy to then select it. And I'm surprised that it can't translate the Any() to an IN. I had assumed it would.

Comment: Just remember that for local collections EF Core supports only `Contains` operator.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Is there some listing somewhere about what function calls go to native SQL? I assume that some of that is per underlying SQL vendor which in my case is Azure SQL Database for production and SQL Express for dev/test (which I don't care how they implement it).

Comment: Are. you looking for this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select().Contains() one simply translates to `WHERE CountryID IN (comma-separated CountryIDs)` because in this case you are just passing a collection of simple values.

With the Any() one, you are passing a list of complex objects to EF which cannot be easily translated to SQL like the above example.

Comment: Correct, but you can remove the word "easily". It just can't be translated.

Comment: @GertArnold, not agree, it can be translated via [VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/select-selecting-from-the-values-table-value-constructor).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Sure, but EF isn't able to do it, is what I mean. Of course they could add support for it. So far, they don't.

Comment: @GertArnold That's what tripped me up - it can be translated so I assumed it had been.